# Синхронизация баз MySql

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

У меня есть сервер. На нем крутится сайт с базой (глобальный). Есть 2 локальных сервера, в каждого своя БД, но она точно такая как на глобальном. В каждой базе в таблицах есть понятие `server_id`. Например, в первого локального он равен 1, во второго - 2.

Суть задачи: если что то изменилось на глобальном (вставка, удаление, редактирование), надо что бы данных передались на нужный локальный сервер. И наоборот: если на локальном что то изменилось - глобальный должен получить эти изменения.

Можно что бы это происходило не моментально, а по крону (на локальном может быть обрыв интернета).

Все сайты написаны на php (фреймворк Yii2)

Comment: выкинуть server_id, по крону делать дамп глобального и заливать на локальные.

Comment: @Ипатьев а как быть, "если на локальном что то изменилось - глобальный должен получить эти изменения"?

Comment: Если бы не было требования "не моментально" (обрыв интернета), то я бы сказал, что нужно настроить репликацию на каждом сервере Мастер-Слейв.  По другому задачу не решить. Ваше предложение "по крону" работать не будет.

Comment: @ArchDemon, а можно подробнее о вашем варианте?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/bitrix/blog/146490/ ищите в поисковике "mysql репликация мастер-мастер"